# How can I fire a key press or mouse click event without touching any input device at system level?

Tags: windows, events

How can I fire an automatic key press or mouse click event when a color appears on the screen
on other application or browser?

Comment: Would you accept answers that aren't in C#, C++, or VB?

Comment: Yes in any language.... please tell..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends a lot on what you want. Do you want to send the keys to

- your Application
- another fixed Application
- Simulate a global keypress

### Simulating keys globally

All of these will cause problems targeting a specific application and the active window changes.

- [`SendKeys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) Sends Messages to the active app. It's a high level function taking a string which encodes a sequence of keys.
- [`keybd_event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646304.aspx) is very low level and injects a global keypress. In most cases `SendKeys` is easier to use.
- [`mouse_event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646260.aspx) simulates mouse input.
- [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310.aspx) supersedes these functions. It's more flexible but a bit harder to use.

### Sending to a specific window

When working with a fixed target window, sending it messages can work depending on how the window works. But since this [doesn't update all states](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/30/423202.aspx) it might not always work. But you don't have a race condition with changing window focus, which is worth a lot.

- [`WM_CHAR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646276.aspx) sends a character in the basic multilingual plane (16 bit)
- [`WM_UNICHAR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646288.aspx) sends a character supporting the whole unicode range
- [`WM_KEYDOWN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280.aspx) and [`WM_KEYUP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646281.aspx) Sends keys which will be translated to characters by the keyboard layout.

My recommendation is when targeting a specific window/application try using messages first, and only if that fails try one of the lower level solutions.

Answer (score 1):

> when a color appears on the screen on other application or browser

I made one program using OpenCV and C++ for operating mouse with finger gesture. I used 3 color strips for 3 mouse function.

- Yellow color for Left click
- Blue color for Right click
- Pink color for controlling cursor position

Whenever camera detect these colors, associated function takes place, I have used [mouse_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646260.aspx) for performing mouse function.
For more information you may read my [code](https://github.com/udit043/Mouse-Control-with-hand-finger-gesture-OpenCV-/blob/master/Finger%20Gesture.cpp#L129), [blog](http://udit043.blogspot.in/2016/01/controlling-mouse-with-finger-gesture.html), [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QlLUvOuWeLE).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you want, but if all you are after is running the method linked the the `button.Clicked` event, then you can manually run the method just like any other method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .NET SendKeys class to send keystrokes.
Emulating mouse clicks requires P/Invoke.
I don't know how to detect colors on the screen.