# How can I make C++ press spacebar?

Tags: c++, sendmessage

So I'm trying to create this little Bunnyhop hack using C++, I've got everything done except this last part, which is what I need help for! :)
Here is my code:

```
if (m_fFlags == FL_ONGROUND) {
    // here is where I want to make it press space!
}
```

This is a short question, thanks! :)

EDIT: What im looking for is something that does kind of the same thing as this:

```
 mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

but with space bar!

Comment: It is not in standard C++. You need some platform specific library. Look into [Qt](http://qt-project.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to use either SendInput() or keybd_event() (which is an older way of doing the same thing).

If you use Visual C++: SendKeys.Send("{SPACE BAR}");

EDIT: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057810/how-can-i-fire-a-key-press-or-mouse-click-event-without-touching-any-input-device) could help you.

Answer (score 3):

The way to send a key on Windows is the [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

```
#include <windows.h>
// ...
INPUT space = {0};
space.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
space.ki.wVk = VK_SPACE;
SendInput(1, &space, sizeof(INPUT)); // Send KeyDown
space.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
SendInput(1, &space, sizeof(INPUT)); // Send KeyUp
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you tried to do a Csgo Bhop ?
When you want to simulate the Space key you can use keybd_event(VK_SPACE, 0, 0, 0);