# Simulate keyboard key press

Tags: c++

I have a simple question about simulate keypress. I want to know that does it have any method to simulate key press like a system level meaning maybe like a real person typing a keyboard. Because the application that I want to simulate key press it block every things(Except writing a code to Arduino then communicate with Arduino to simulate key press).By the way I am just begin learning C++. I can't create my own keyboard driver by now.

I have done testing with:

```
1. keybd_event(Not working)
2. Sendmessage(Not working)
3. PostMessage(Not working)
4. SendInput(Not working)
5. Arduino Leonardo(Working by communicate with the board)
```

Arduino leonardo is working very well. But I want it to be more simple by just using only my laptop.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fire a key press or mouse click event without touching any input device at system level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057810/how-can-i-fire-a-key-press-or-mouse-click-event-without-touching-any-input-devic)

Comment: @JohnSmith No. I had already test all method. it's work fine in another application. But in my application it have been blocked.

Comment: can you tell us what is the application do you want to send keypressed to? That may help us know why they get blocked and how to circumvent it

Comment: @JohnSmith It is a game that contain DINPUT.dll. The purpose is to send a key to this process without focus. Or helping player to press multicharacter while pressing only 1 keypress